# Will the Quorum disk effect the running cluster and cluster IP?

Tags: sql-server

we have three servers. one is for Quorum disk,another two nodes for SQLserver in Cluster and Quorum disk configured in the cluster.
Windows Admin want to restart the machine but it has Quorum disk, so will it effect the running cluster and cluster IP will be available or not.
Please advise.

Comment: It's too late now, but this is the sort of thing to test before a cluster goes live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removal of the quorum disk removes witness from the cluster which means it will not sustain any failure.

You probably already know this that you can have a file share as your Quorum in a cluster setup (only in windows server 2008 and later) I would suggest the following steps for restarting the Server where Quorum disk is located.

1. Create a file share on the network somewhere.
2. Move your Cluster Quorum to that file share.
3. Restart the server where Quorum was located before.
4. Once server is back on , move the Quorum back to that disk.

This approach will keep your cluster available during the whole process as it will have a Quorum to trigger a failover in case of a failure on any of the clustered nodes.